# Incorrect outputs for toString method for List implementation

Tags: java, hashmap, tostring

I am implementing a generic List class and not getting the expected output.

My current output is:
[0, 1, null]

Expected Output in a separate test class:

```
List list = new SparseList<>(); 
list.add("0");
list.add("1");
list.add(4, "4");
```

will result in the following list of size 5: [0, 1, null, null, 4].

```
list.add(3, "Three");
```

will result in the following list of size 6: [0, 1, null, Three, null, 4].

```
list.set(3, "Three");
```

is going to produce a list of size 5 (unchanged): [0, 1, null, Three, 4].

When removing an element from the list above, via
list.remove(1);
the result should be the following list of size 4: [0, null, Three, 4]

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class SparseList<E> implements List<E>{
    private int endIndex = 0;
    
    private HashMap<Integer,E> list;
    
    public SparseList() {
        list = new HashMap<>();
    }
    
    public SparseList(E[] arr) {
        list = new HashMap<>();
        for(int i = 0; i <arr.length; i++) {
            list.put(i, arr[i]);
        }
        endIndex = arr.length - 1;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean add(E e) {
        list.put(endIndex, e);
        endIndex++;
        return true;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void add(int index, E element) {
        List<E> l = (List<E>) list.get(index);  
    if(l == null) { 
         l = new ArrayList<E>(); 
         l.add(element); 
         list.put(index, (E) l); 
    } else { 
        if(!((List<E>) list).contains(element)) ((List<E>) 
   list).add(element); 
    } 
    }
    
    @Override
    public E remove(int index) {
        return list.remove(index);
    }
    
    @Override
    public E get(int index) {
        return list.get(index);
    }
    
    @Override
    public E set(int index, E element) {
        E previous = list.get(index);
        list.put(index, element);
        return previous;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int size() {
        return endIndex + 1;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        list.clear();
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return list.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String s = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if(list.get(i) == null) {
                s += "null, ";
            }else {
            s += list.get(i).toString() + ", ";
        }
        }
        return "[" + s + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] toArray() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends E> c) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
    
    @Override
    public int indexOf(Object o) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public int lastIndexOf(Object o) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public ListIterator<E> listIterator() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public ListIterator<E> listIterator(int index) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public List<E> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

}
```

Comment: Edit your answer to fix this typo:
`list.set(3, "Three);` -> `list.set(3, "Three");`

Comment: what output are you getting? I assume the issue is that you'd need to actually move things around when adding or removing in the middle of the list. You'll have to shift the indices of all the values above the index you are touching

Comment: What do you mean by "*result*"?

Comment: Show toString scenario and return (expected and current).

Answer (score -1):

Your `public void add(int index, E element)` is broken going by your specification that is implied by these two lines :

> list.add(4, "4");
>
> will result in the following list of size 5: [0, 1, null, null, 4].

The index you use in this method is never going to affect the size of the hashMap , which in turn is not going to result in the `toString()` behaving how you expect.

Comment: No, endIndex does not affect the hashMap size either, You need to read the specs for HashMap and understand that thers no concept of adding an element at an index ( even less correlating that to the size of the map )